# how to connect php database file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jvectormap

I have using Jvector Map as a default Jvector map its working hover function.Now i changed hover to click function.but now i want display country details from  database.i  have created php database? i don't know how to call my database php file?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Country Footprint</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../jquery-jvectormap.css"/>
  <script src="assets/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <-- jvectormap scripts here -->
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
      var $ = jQuery;
      $('#focus-single').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-init').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
      });

      $('#map1').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        panOnDrag: true,
        focusOn: {
          x: 0.5,
          y: 0.5,
          scale: 1,
          animate: true
        },
        series: {
          regions: [{
            scale: ['#688FA0'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: thank you for comment. i have try it but not connected

Answer (score 2):

The answer is easy but you will need to do some more coding.

First of all you need to realize, that you JavaScript application can't connect to your database directly (and if it could, you'd have to store you database credentials in your JS app and reveal them to everyone out there).

JavaScript apps usually get the data using AJAX - you need to have a webserver configured that at a certain endpoint (eg. `http://example.com/getdata.php`) returning a JSON response. That can be then loaded in your JS app.

The `getdata.php` script is just a simple PHP script, that connects to the database and selects all required data and encodes them to JSON and writes to the output (don't forget to add `Content-Type: application/json` header).